# Pyinstaller issues for Windows 10 to Windows 8.1

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to create a standalone application using Pyinstaller on Windows 10. But when I try to execute it one Windows 8.1, it does not run (It works fine on every Windows 10 machine). Is it possible to specify compatibility or make the application generally accessible across various windows Operating Systems.

I used the following code while creating the application

```
      pyinstaller -F -w --onefile file_name.py
```

Is there anything I should add to this or is there any addition required in the python code itself?

I get the following pop-ups when I put --debug during compiling:

```
[2252] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x  
[2252] Loader: executable is [FILE-PATH]  
[2252] LOADER: homepath is [FILE-DIRECTORY]  
[2252] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL  
[2252] LOADER: archivename is [FILE_PATH]  
[2252] LOADER: Extracting binaries  
[2252] LOADER: Executing self as child  
[2252] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI22522  
[2252] LOADER: Setting up to run child  
[2252] LOADER: Creating child process  
[2252] LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish  
[2252] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI22522  
[2792] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code  
[2792] LOADER: manifestpath: [FILE_TEMP_PATH].manifest  
[2792] LOADER: Activation context created  
[2792] LOADER: ACtivation context activated  
[2792] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI22522\python27.dll  
[2792] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library  
[2792] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)  
[2792] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI22~1  
[2792] LOADER: Setting runtime options   
[2792] LOADER: Initializing python  
[2792] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path  
[2792] LOADER: Post -init sys,path is [PATH_TO_ _MEI22522]  
[2792] LOADER: Setting sys.argv  
[2792] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS  
[2792] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive  
[2792] LOADER: extracted struct  
[2792] LOADER: callfunction returned  
[2792] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path  
[2792] LOADER: callfunction returned  
[2792] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_archive  
[2792] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.  
Failed to execute [FILE_NAME]
```

WebDriverWait(driver,10000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,'body')))

Comment: Could you please add the error message you are receiving when running the program in Windows 8.1? You can easily view the error associated with running your .exe file by launching the program from the command prompt.